# Itext line spacing with irregular columns not working

Tags: itext

I am using Itext with irregular columns.Itext version is 5.5.9.
I am not able to set the line spacing.
I am using the following code:

```
ColumnText ct= new ColumnText(); 
ct.setLeading(6f);
```

but using setLeading is having no effect.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is incomplete because you don't show how you add content to the `ct`, but I think that you are adding the content in **composite mode** (which ignores the leading of the column) instead of in **text mode** (which takes the properties of the column).

So either you have to change the way you add the content, or you have to change the way you set the leading.

This is **text mode**:

```
ColumnText ct= new ColumnText(); 
ct.setLeading(6f);
ct.addText(new Chunk("Hello"));
ct.addText(new Chunk("World"));
```

This is **composite mode**:

```
ColumnText ct= new ColumnText(); 
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Hello World ... Long sentence, etc.");
p.setLeading(6f);
ct.addElement(p);
```

In the **composite mode** example, it doesn't make sense to define the leading for `ct` because it will be overruled by the leading of the `Paragraph`. The default leading of the `Paragraph` is 1.5 times the font size. So if you set the leading for the column to 6, but you add a paragraph with the default font size using composite mode, the leading will be 18 (1.5 times 12).

**Update:**

You can not use `Paragraph`s in text mode. When you do, the `Paragraph`s are treated as `Phrase`s, and they take the leading of the `ColumnText`. All text in text mode will have the same leading in the same `go()`. One thing you could do, is call `go()` different times:

```
ColumnText ct= new ColumnText(); 
ct.setLeading(6f);
ct.addText(new Chunk("Hello blah blah ... blah"));
ct.go(); 
ct.setLeading(12f);
ct.addText(new Chunk("Hello blah blah ... blah"));
ct.go();
```

Comment: Hi Dear, I am using Text Mode but the issue is that I have 2 paragraphs in it and I want different line spacing in both of them.If i use setLeading multiple times only the latest one seems to have effect. I tried using composite mode as an alternative for this so that the paragraph spacing can be used but it said "Irregular columns not allowed in composite mode"

Comment: You can not use `Paragraph`s in text mode. When you do, the `Paragraph`s are treated as `Phrase`s, and they take the leading of the `ColumnText`. All text in text mode will have the same leading. You can only have a different leading in composite mode. However, they might be a workaround. I will update my answer.